# Docker Service won't start Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, containers, windows-server-2016

I followed the steps in [this](https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/) link to install Docker on Windows Server 2016.

`OS Name  Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard
Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393`

Docker installs fine, but the service just stays in "Starting" when I restart the server. There are no Docker related messages in the event logs, so I have absolutely no idea what the problem is. I also tried deregistering the service, and registering it listening on the default named pipe and an IP address.

Comment: Did you run the commands in an *Administrative* PowerShell prompt?

Comment: Yes I did. You get an error when you try running it without, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Hello, this guide is more actual: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server

Comment: The link you suggested worked. But I don't completely understand why, because it calls the same commands to install docker? The only other thing that I changed is I didn't join the Server 2016 instance to our domain. Is your instances on a domain?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the docker Service didn't start after fresh Installation cause I already had a Hyper-V Switch type NAT and a corresponding NETNAT object. Docker for Windows is trying to create a new NETNAT object for it's HNS internal Network, and can't do so, cause the other NETNAT object already exists.
I remove the Hyper-V Switch and the NETNAT object ( get-netnat | remove-netnat), and after that the Installation for Docker on Windows Server 2016 worked without any Problems - and the Docker Service was started automatically after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you get `Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default network: HNS failed with error : The object already exists.`
Try doing `New-ContainerNetwork nat` and then `Start-Service docker` again.

It took me a couple of hours to figure this out and nothing is documented anywhere. It was a wild guess thanks to https://juniper.github.io/contrail-windows-docs/Known_issues/HNS_error_bestiary/

> 4. HNS failed with error : {Object Exists} An attempt was made to create an object and the object name already exists
>    When it happens
>    This error probably happens when docker tries to create NAT network, but HNS left over some trash after last NAT network.

> Cleanup everything as explained in the Decontamination Procedures chapter. If the problem still persists, just create a random NAT network:

> `New-ContainerNetwork foo`